# Intellij IDEA - run all unit tests before launching the application with a single click

Tags: intellij-idea

always before launching my app I'm running all the unit tests to make sure there is no regression. So I have two separate tasks and run all tests, and then I launch the app.

I'm curious if there is any option of setting the configuration this way that I click "Run" button, and it invokes build, tests and launch?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-compound.html.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately the page says `The following is only valid when Ruby or Python Plugin is installed and enabled!`

Comment: That is not true, give it a try.

Comment: thanks, that was really quick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA provides [Compound Run/Debug configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-compound.html) exactly for that:

> Use this dialog box to create configurations containing multiple run/debug configurations that you can launch at once. This is useful, for example, if you want to launch various automated tests and get test results in one window.

Comment: Instruction: create separate "All tests" and "Run" configurations,
go to run configurations,
click "+" (new),
pick "Compound",
on the right add your configurations in a proper order

Comment: The Maven settings (Build - Maven - Runner) have an option to "Skip Tests". If unchecked, maven tests are run whenever a maven/java runner starts.
(A coworker had the issue that all 2000 tests were executed before anything starts - even before tests, wasn't fun)